# Cassandra bitwise operations and operators (&, or, not)

Tags: database, cassandra, operators, nosql

My use case is the following: 
I have a table that has a bigint **clustering column X**. I also have a **value Y that is a bitmask** in this use case. I want to do the following query

```
select * from table where key1 = something1 AND key2 = something2 AND (X & Y) = 1
```

where the & is the bitwise and operation between X and Y. Is this possible in cassandra?
Also does cassandra have and, or, xor and not operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Cassandra "operators" are limited to >, >=, <= and >

They are used in range queries on the sorted clustering column after having selected a primary key.

What you want would be a sort of filtering, not a range query.

You can read the post here to know more about the WHERE clause: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause